# Using wp_mail during an integration test

Tags: testing, unit-tests

I'm working on some tests for WordPress, and I discovered that WordPress' PHPUnit automatically captures and doesn't send emails (using `MockPHPMailer`) when I try to use `wp_mail`.

I've looked, but I can't seem to find any information on `MockPHPMailer`. I'd love to know either how to use it or disable it (since before this discovery I'd planned to use Mailtrap). Does anyone know where I might find some information about `MockPHPMailer`?

Comment: `wp_mail` is a pluggable function then you can replace it

Comment: What would be an example of replacing it with the original `PHPMailer`?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was working on some tests for code that involved `wp_mail()` just the other day. I couldn't find any docs on it either, but I took a look at [the source of `mock-mailer.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/tests/phpunit/includes/mock-mailer.php), and everything was rather simple.

First, you should understand that WordPress always uses the `$phpmailer` global to hold an instance of the `PHPMailer` object that is used by `wp_mail()`. During the tests, the `$phpmailer` global is automatically [set to be an instance of `MockPHPMailer`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/4.6/tests/phpunit/includes/bootstrap.php#L50) instead.

The `MockPHPMailer` doesn't actually send any mail, it just collects information about each message that is "sent". To retrieve this information, you can call the object's `get_sent()` method. To retrieve the object itself, it looks like `tests_retrieve_phpmailer_instance()` is intended to be used.

So in a simple test where you just want to check that no mail was sent, you'd do this:

```
    $this->assertEmpty( tests_retrieve_phpmailer_instance()->get_sent() );
```

Of course, you can also perform more complex checks like this (a real-life example from my own tests):

```
    $email = tests_retrieve_phpmailer_instance()->get_sent();

    $this->assertEquals( array( array( 'test@example.com', '' ) ), $email->to );

    $this->assertStringMatchesFormat( '%sItem 03%s', $email->body );
    $this->assertStringMatchesFormat( '%sA Donor%s', $email->body );
    $this->assertStringMatchesFormat(
        '%s' . get_the_title( $wish_list_id ) . '%s'
        , $email->body
    );
```

The email object returned by `get_sent()` has [the following properties](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/tests/phpunit/includes/mock-mailer.php#L15):

- `to`
- `cc`
- `bcc`
- `header`
- `subject`
- `body`

If you are expecting multiple emails to be sent in a single test, you can retrieve the second one with `get_sent( 1 )`, the third one with `get_sent( 2 )`, and so on (they are stored in a 0-indexed array).

If you want to reset the mailer and discard the captured messages in the middle of a test, you can call `reset_phpmailer_instance()` (as of WordPress 4.6). You'll also want to do this after each test, by implementing a `tearDown()` method like this in your testcase class:

```
public function tearDown() {

    parent::tearDown();

    reset_phpmailer_instance();
}
```

And finally, if you want to use the original `PHPMailer` instance in your tests instead of the mock mailer, just try calling `unset( $GLOBALS['phpmailer'] )`.

Comment: Is it possible to mock the failure of sending an email? I've looked at the core tests, and I copy/pasted the test in my integration test but it failed (you must provide at least one recipient email address). http://develop.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/tests/phpunit/tests/mail.php
I have a method that is hooked on `wp_mail_failed` and would like to test it...